# DynamoDB avoid duplicate non-key attributes

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, amazon-dynamodb

I have a user object with these attributes.

`id` (key), `name` and `email`

And I am trying to make sure these attributes are unique in the DB.

How do I prevent a `put`/`create`/`save` operation from succeeding, in case of either of the non-key attributes, `email` and `name`, already exists in the DB?

I have a table, `tblUsers` with one key-attribute being the `id`.
I then have two globally secondary indexes, each with also one key-attribute, being the `email` for the first index-table, and `name` for the second.

I am using microsoft .net identity framework, which itself checks for existing users with a given name or email, before creating a user.

The problem I forsee, is the delay between checking for existing users and creating a new. There is no safety, that multiple threads wont end up creating two users with the same name or email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dynamodb can force uniqueness only for hash-range table keys (not for global secondary index keys)

do in your case there are 2 options:

1) force it on application level - if your problem is safety, then use locks (cache locks)

2) dont use dynamodb (maybe its not answer your requirements )

Comment: Havent thought about locks - I guess that is my best option - lock -> check for duplicate -> create -> release

Answer (score 0):

I am using ehcache locally to check for duplicates . Adding one more check if ehcache is empty (for some reason ,cache has been reset ) .repopulate cache by making query to dynamoDb .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case, I found I used the same attribute 2 times.